# How to integrate .css and .js with ReactJS + Redux architecture?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, redux

I am currently following http://callmenick.com/post/animated-resizing-header-on-scroll and downloaded the source code and it has the following:

[image]

I am using ReactJS + Redux, and Webpack. How should I integrate those files to my ReactJS architecture? For example, I don't want to throw everything into my current index.html file even though it is possible, and that is not following ReactJS.

**EDIT**

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import actions from '../redux/actions'

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          Content
        </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return state
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App)
```

My current index.html set up:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Practice Example</title>

    <meta name="description" content="Practice Example">

    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1"
    >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script>
      var WebFontConfig = {
        google: { families: [ 'Roboto:400,300,500:latin' ] }
      };
      (function() {
        var wf = document.createElement('script');
        wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
        '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        wf.type = 'text/javascript';
        wf.async = 'true';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
      })();
    </script>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2 - webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './client/client.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: require("path").resolve("./dist"),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'react-hmre', 'stage-0']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically you want to build your CSS/LESS/SCSS stylesheets using Webpack. You'll want to grab style-loader and the style-loader for each markup you're using. Then, you set up a module that tests your stylesheets and loaders them with the style-loader.

```
{
    // ...
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
        ]
    }
}
```

It's all here https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html

EDIT

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './client/client.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: require("path").resolve("./dist"),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'react-hmre', 'stage-0']
        }
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loader: "style-loader!sass-loader" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated the original post with `App.js` and my `index.html`. I only would want to implement the nav bar to the `App.js`. Could you show an example with `App.js` with what you suggested? Like how to call the .css, and how the module should set up, and where should the source code `index.html` and `classie.js` be and called from? Looked at the site but need better clarification. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you also post your webpack.config.js file?
As for how to include it, you'll want to import the stylesheet just like you would a JavaScript class. For example, if you have a React Component App.js, and it's styled in App.css, you would import it into your App.js with this:
import './App.css'
At the top of your JS.
For your particular case I would first look for a React library with similar functionality to that library. Otherwise your best bet is build a React wrapper around it.

Comment: Appreciate the clarification! Just added the webpack.config.js in the original post under EDIT 2.

Comment: So you'll want to add loaders for CSS and SCSS in the way I posted in my answer. 
But, that'll only help you with code that's referenced by client.js or a descendant of client.js.
So, if you want to use a non-React library in your React code, you'll have to write a React wrapper. 
That said, if you can find a React library it will fit neater with your code and take advantage of React.

Comment: Sorry but do you mind editing your answer and showing for clarification as to how to add loaders? And what are you referring to for a non-React library? Lastly, what's the properly React way to integrate those source code `index.html` and `classie.js` into mine for `App.js` to use?

Comment: By a non-React library I simply mean anything that doesn't provide a React Component. 
To adapt code into a React Component, you'll want to convert the necessary HTML into JSX that's rendered by a React Component. You'll also want to adapt the provided JavaScript into class methods. 
That said, you'll have to do a fair bit of re-writing to make it work properly. Briefly, you don't want to do your own DOM-manipulation inside React. You simply want a Render function that describe how your Component should look based on it's props/state.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Do you mind providing a guide as to how I should start? First of al, I just can't seem to wrap my head around to where and how the source code `index.html` and `classie.js` should work and be placed.

Comment: just checking to see if you've read my previous comment. Please let me know.

Comment: What have done in React so far? I would recommend learning how React works and trying some samples first. Because, in essence, you will be building your own React Component, just with existing code.

Comment: Just the environment set up with `App.js`. I first want to get this running properly. So would the `classie.js` be called from the `App.js` component?

Comment: If you can help, I would really appreciate it... been working on this all day yesterday after researching, yet still no luck.